# ORACLE: Simulate READ UNCOMMITTED Behavior

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, concurrency

With Oracle, I need to allow another transaction to view uncommitted data or data that will be rolled back if the transaction that changed it does not complete successfully.

Let's look at the example:

Arrange

```
CREATE TABLE Car
(
   Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   Building NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Car (Name, Building) VALUES ('Car 1', 0);
```

Act

CONNECTION 1

```
UPDATE Car SET Building = 1 WHERE Name = 'Car 1';
```

CONNECTION 2

```
SELECT * FROM Car;
```

Result:

```
Name       Building
===================
'Car 1'  |  1
         |

--Should be able to view the new Building value (1/true) from CONNECTION1 before 
--the CONNECTION1 transaction be commited.
```

CONNECITON 1

```
--Do a lot of work to build the car (20seconds), then sets the Building flag to 0 and commits the transaction.
```

It can be reached using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED on CONNECTION2 in SQL Server, but not in Oracle, it does not have this option.

I need provided end user to view that a car is beign builded and I need make sure if some fail occurs in the car build process (like energy fail), the Building flag returns to 0/false.

Comment: This is a very curious requirement.  What are you really trying to do?  Why not just commit the `update` immediately?

Comment: If I commit and some fail occurs I will let the Building flag on 1/true forever and I need guarantee that this value comes back to 0 whenever I set to 1/true.

Answer (score 2):

> I need provided end user to view that a car is beign builded and I need make sure if some fail occurs in the car build process (like energy fail), the Building flag returns to 0/false.

Instead of (or in addition to) using a boolean flag, why not manage a list of possible states, like:

- `0` - new
- `1` - build in progress
- `2` - build failed
- `3` - built successfully

That way, you can have the connection that handles the build update the state at the beginning and end of the process (and always commit immediatly). On the other connection, you can follow the lifecycle of the item.

Comment: The user submits a car for build.
I set the build status to "build in progress" and commit.
Other users can view the new status, ok.
The build process crashes due to a power failure.
I need at this time the status of Build Failed to be set, I can not leave as the "build in progress", so how can I achieve it? My app is down at this moment.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: OK I see your point: if your application crashes, then one solution is to change all builds in progress to failed *after each application restart*, like so: `update mytable set status = 2 where status = 1`.

Comment: In a multi-instance application like when using containers, there are a lot of instances handling some "in progress" status :/ So I can't do that.